# How my app can know when user logout from its Android native Facebook app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

How my app can know when user logout from its native Facebook app ?

I am using below code for Logging out from Facebook in my app. And it is working fine.

```
class LogoutTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            if (facebook.isSessionValid()) {
                try {
                    facebook.logout(getApplicationContext());
                    editLoginStatus(false);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putString("access_token", null);
                    editor.putLong("access_expires",
                            facebook.getAccessExpires());
                    editor.commit();

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }
```

But problem is occurring when user logging out from its native Facebook app and then clicking on the logout button on my app.

It showing me following error

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
 at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid context argument
 at android.webkit.CookieSyncManager.createInstance(CookieSyncManager.java:86)
 at com.facebook.internal.Utility.clearCookiesForDomain(Utility.java:319)
 at com.facebook.internal.Utility.clearFacebookCookies(Utility.java:343)
 at com.facebook.Session.closeAndClearTokenInformation(Session.java:798)
 at com.facebook.android.Facebook.logoutImpl(Facebook.java:665)
 at com.facebook.android.Facebook.logout(Facebook.java:642)
 at com.example.animation.StartLoginActivity$LogoutTask.doInBackground(StartLoginActivity.java:328)
 at com.example.animation.StartLoginActivity$LogoutTask.doInBackground(StartLoginActivity.java:1)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

and I am calling this function as below

```
if (facebook.getAccessToken() != null && facebook.isSessionValid() == true) {
    new LogoutTask().execute();
}
```

here accessToken I am storing locally in sharedPreference , so it won't be null as long as I am not logging out from my app , but I guess after logging out from native FB app `facebook.isSessionValid()` should return false while it is returning true .So how to check to know Facebook app is already logging out or not ?

Comment: Someone said to me that after user logged out then previous session will be outdated. So now my question is how I can check that session is outdated or not ?

Answer (score 1):

on destroy you clear the session and token information so that if you logout from your native application .. it will clear its credentials

use this

```
  @Override 
  protected void onDestroy() {

   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onDestroy();
 Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
 session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();


  }
```

OR

```
   public void logoutFromFacebook() {
   mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new RequestListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);
        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(response) == true) {
            // User successfully Logged out
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
            Object state) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
            Object state) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
    }
});
}
```

try this it works for me .. so it will also resolve your issue also

Comment: I am not using `Session.getActiveSession()` for storing my session data rather I am using `facebook.getSession`. So when I am writing
`facebook.getSession.closeAndClearTokenInformation()` in OnDestroy  it showing me 
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid context argument` error.

Comment: see again answer i have updated .. or u can refer this url http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Comment: Still having same error , It showing `Invalid context argument` while clicking on Logout button

Comment: there this exception is about passing context problem.. so instead of passing " this " please pass this.getApplicationContext()


Certainly, this is not the best solution, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Still no luck, I tried that as well as tried only `getApplicationContext()` also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59842/discussion-between-kunu-and-vaishali).

Answer (score 1):

Try to check if there's a Facebook account in the system.

```
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
Account[] facebookAccounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.facebook.auth.login");
if (facebookAccounts.length > 0) {
    facebook.logout(getApplicationContext());
    ...
}
```

Yes, the code contains hard-coded account type, which is slightly unreliable due to possible changes in the native app, though the probability of such changes is very small.

And don't forget to add a [GET_ACCOUNTS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#GET_ACCOUNTS) permission to the Manifest.

Comment: If user log out from Facebook native app then session will be outdated ,but if he again login from the facebook app session will be a different one however in this method facebookAccounts.length will return 1

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm... It may be get tricky. I guess the isSessionValid is offline checking from the FB API.

From your situation, it looks like you still need to have a single call to the FB to check the session is really valid or not. So my suggestion based on your situation is to make simple FB API call such as `/me` just to check the validity of the session.

If session is valid, then you manually call the logout API, otherwise, you know that the FB session is either expired/logged out.

Hope helps
:)